# Can Azure Service Fabric run a DCOM server with unmanaged code?

Tags: azure, com, unmanaged, dcom, azure-service-fabric

I've started reading on Azure Service Fabric - well, it's quite a lot of new concepts and I cannot immediately find whether this thing allows to run unmanaged code. We have a DCOM component worth 7 million lines of hardcore C++ code and we absolutely need it. If Service Fabric cannot run unmanaged code we won't even consider it.

Can Azure Servie Fabric run unmanaged code (and specifically DCOM servers)?

Comment: I'd say it can, but how will you deploy your component?  Is it closed source or can you adapt it?  I think the only distributed part of DCOM, or COM+ distributed components, that you can take advantage of here is load-balancing activation (does that still exist for COM+?).  Due to the communication overhead (round-trips for activation, request and release), you should keep the COM server close to the clients.  Or make micro-webservices that actually perform the COM calls for the clients (a long time ago, you could turn on SOAP for the COM+ component).

Comment: @PauloMadeira Well, we currently use web roles and we just download the binaries from blob storage and then run the DCOM server executable with a command line parameter and it installs itself. I guess we could do the same here.

Comment: OK, so the (D)COM component is actually local and you already have web services wrapping or using them, is that it?

Comment: @PauloMadeira Yes it is local to each service instance and we also have IIS which has an ASP.NET application running and making use of the local DCOM component instance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Normally these types of existing apps are deployed as [Guest Executables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-existing-app). In this case the DCOM executable becomes the main code entry point described in your service manifest. If you already have a redistributable package of all those binaries, you might even be able to just follow the quickstart [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/quickstart-guest-app).